# How to pass selected sql row id from dynamic query results to javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

i have a php page with a table populating dynamic sql query results.  if i click on one row, how am I going to pass the row id of that item by javascript?

thanks.

Comment: Show (perhaps a cut-down example of) your existing code for the table element. Are you saying you want the click event on the row to call a JavaScript function and pass the row ID as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#table-id tr').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```